# According to Liouville's theorem, why is the measure on an energy-surface different from the measure on the phase space in general

Tags: physics, symplectic-geometry

I recently read Khinchin's derivation of Liouville's theorem. I was able to follow the math for the most part, however I was hoping for an intuitive understanding about why the form of the measure on an energy surface in phase space is different than the form of the measure on the whole phase space

If we have an n-dimensional phase space then the measure on that phase space is simply $dV$. I was able to follow the proof about why that measure is conserved under the natural motion. However, if we restrict our analysis to an energy surface to that phase space then the measure on that surface becomes $\frac{d \Sigma}{| \nabla H |}$, and not just $d \Sigma,$ the area element on that energy surface. From what I understand, the stated reason for this is that $d \Sigma \cdot dn = \frac{d \Sigma}{| \nabla H |}$ (where $dn$ is the normal to the energy surface) is just a volume element in the phase space, and we can then appeal to the fact that we already know that a differential volume element in phase space is conserved. However, if we view the energy surface itself as an $N-1$ dimensional phase space then your old $d \Sigma$ essentially becomes a volume element in this new $N-1$ dimensional space. Why, then, does Liouville's theorem as derived for the higher dimensional phase space not also apply to the $N-1$ dimensional space, thus making $d \Sigma$ the correct measure?

Comment: See my answer here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299774/volume-form-on-hamiltonian-level-surface/1178519#1178519

Comment: + The Liouville form is for $\mathbb{R}^n$ spaces only. The generalization of this to arbitrary manifolds is the notion of a symplectic form which is only defined on even dimensional manifolds. If you restrict your symplectic form to a codimension 1 (which is odd) manifold it is no longer a symplectic form and the restriction of the Hamiltonian flow to these energy surfaces is not the Hamiltonian flow of some symplectic form on this surface.